# how to add color to the points to denote the values of another variable

Tags: r, colors, maps, points

```
library(maps)
map("state","California")
points(map$x,map$y)
```

I use the command above created a  map with points that represent the houses location.
how can I add colors to these points on the map to denote the values of 
another variable Z(which represent house value for example) ?

Comment: which package are you using? maps?

Comment: http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Colors%20(ggplot2)/

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - I think using ggplot might be a bit of overkill when all you need to do is add a `col=` to the `points` statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(maps)
map("state","California")
```

Make some test data. I have changed the data name from `map` to `mappts` so it doesn't clash with the base function. It's not a good idea to name data the same name as a function.

```
dput(mappts)
structure(list(x = c(-121.837504273717, -119.288648121568, -116.37566966197
), y = c(40.0189660554, 36.8188807085794, 34.5400320525101)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
mappts$z <- c(1,2,3)

> mappts
          x        y
1 -121.8375 40.01897
2 -119.2886 36.81888
3 -116.3757 34.54003
```

Add a `z` column

```
mappts$z <- c(1,2,3)
points(mappts,col=mappts$z,pch=19)
```

[image: take me down to the paradise city]

If your `z` column is not grouped so neatly, you may need to recode it first.

If you would like to specify your colours manually, you can edit the `palette` by doing:

```
palette(c("blue","pink","green"))
```

...which you can then reset using:

```
palette("default")
```